# Using getter and setter on Django based on expiration datetime

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make an automated system that modifies the values of the model when an expiration date(and time) arrives. It's Django 1.9 running over Python 3.

I'm not sure if I'm applying correctly the getter/setter properties as

Here is what I'm doing:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now, localtime
from datetime import *

class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _state = (
            ('1', 'active'),
            ('2', 'inactive'),
        )
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=state, default='active')
    duration = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

@property
def state(self):
    return self.expires > localtime(now())

@state.setter
def state(self):
    if active() == False:
        return self._state = 2

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.created_at = localtime(now())
    self.expires = self.created_at + self.duration
    return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm using underscore to define the default value.
The problem is that there are no changes when the time comes and I don't know how to debug this.

I have two questions:

- Is it possible to use any tool to debug this?
- Is this the correct way to use getter and setter? (I see it very far for this to make it work)

If you know what's going on with this please let me know

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, you just write some functions on the class and expect the model to update by itself when the time comes?

Comment: So you want your model to mark itself as expired when it's been saved, right?

Comment: It doesn't makes sense to me neither. But I'm really lost with this and another user told me this actually works as you can rewrite values on the model.

Comment: @AlexMorozov I want it to change state after it expires.

Comment: You need an external "watchdog" which will trigger your model's state check on a certain schedule. If once a minute is precise enough for you, you could write a management command and call it from your crontab.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what you were told. The other user was presumably talking about a state attribute which, when accessed, returns whether or not the time has expired. But this is presentational only, it won't update the database for you.

Comment: @AlexMorozov Thanks. I'll research about this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes I did. Now I get it.

Comment: The  model does not have to "update itself", it could be lazy, update the status only when called. It's better than watchdog, because it's always updated even between watch intervals. However: (1) any other resource other than django is using the model (if yes, lazy will not do)? and (2) If the status expires, what happens?